# How can i use Default Realm and Realm in memory at the same time?

Tags: ios, realm

As i want to use realm for 2 type of data, One is persistence data and one for realtime data.
I want to use 2 Realm instance at the same time, how to switch between two of this instance of realm.

Answer (score 3):

If my understanding is correct, you mean that you'd like to separate to Realm DB files into two?

If so, you can set different path to Realm Configuration object, then instantiate Realm with the configuration object.

If you'd like to in-memory Realm at same time, you can make another configuration object that is configured in-memory.

Like the following:

```
var config1 = Realm.Configuration()
config1.path = "/path/to/one.realm"
let realm1 = try! Realm(configuration: config2) // This Realm uses one.realm

var config2 = Realm.Configuration()
config2.path = "/path/to/two.realm"
let realm1 = try! Realm(configuration: config2) // This Realm uses two.realm

var config3 = Realm.Configuration()
config3.inMemoryIdentifier = "MyInMemoryRealm"
let realm3 = try! Realm(configuration: config3) // This Realm is memory only
```

Comment: THX! I think u understand my question. as your answer, when i want to select which Realm DB to use just call 
try! Realm(configuration: config) to select db isn't it?

Comment: Yes. I recommend to hold two or more Realm instances as member variables.

Comment: one more question , is in-memory Realm is work for store realtime data?

Comment: What is realm time data? You mean a lot of date will be insert in a short time?

Comment: Yes, no problem. FYI: on Realm, in-memory Realm and file backed Realm are same essentially. Because Realm used memory-mapped file. So in-memory Realm and Realm are mapped to memory in the same way. If you thought that in-memory Realm is much faster than file baked Realm, there are no difference.